# How can I improve the performance of this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a table called People.People which links to a number of other tables. A person may or may not have a row in these tables, depending on the work they do.
I have the following query (saved as a view) which returns a series of booleans depending on whether there are rows in these related tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PersonID,
CASE WHEN av.VisitorID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS VisitorInfo,
CASE WHEN amd.AssociateMemberID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS AssociateMemberInfo,
CASE WHEN phw.PersonWorkloadID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS WorkloadInfo,
CASE WHEN fa.ApplicationID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS FundingInfo,
CASE WHEN ph.PostHolderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS PostHolderInfo,
CASE WHEN foh.FacultyOfficeHolderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS FacultyOfficeHolderInfo,
CASE WHEN ps.PersonSpecialismID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS PersonSpecialismInfo,
CASE WHEN lb.PersonID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS PersonLeaveInfo
FROM People.People p 
LEFT JOIN Visitors.AcademicVisitors av ON p.PersonID = av.PersonID
LEFT JOIN AssociateMembers.AssociateMembershipDetails amd ON p.PersonID = amd.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Workload.PostHolderWorkload phw ON p.PersonID = phw.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Workload.LeaveBooked lb ON p.PersonID=lb.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Finance.FundingApplications fa ON p.PersonID = fa.ApplicantPersonID
LEFT JOIN HR.PostHolders ph ON p.PersonID = ph.PersonID
LEFT JOIN FacultyOffices.FacultyOfficeHolders foh ON p.PersonID = foh.PersonID
LEFT JOIN People.PersonSpecialisms ps ON p.PersonID = ps.PersonID
```

I've suddenly started getting performance problems with this query, which has until now performed fine. The tables are small - only around 600 rows in People, which is the largest of them.

The database is a SQL Azure database, and the recommendation from Microsoft (in their Azure portal performance analyser) was that the database is topping out the available DTUs, and that I should increase the capacity - which I've done, at least as a short term measure, and this has helped a bit.

But is there a more efficient way of achieving what I want by re-writing this query?

Here's the design of the tables including indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE [People].[People](
    [PersonID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Sex] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime] NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [PersonType] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ShowFundingApplications] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TS] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [WebFormID] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ShowAssociateMemberInformation] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ShowVisitorInformation] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ShowPostholdingDetails] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ShowWorkloadDetails] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SSO] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CustomisedShowAssociateInfo] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CustomisedShowVisitorInfo] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CustomisedShowPostholdingInfo] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CustomisedShowFundingInfo] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CustomisedShowWorkloadInfo] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [OriginalID] [int] NULL,
    [OriginalSource] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [LocationDetails] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ShowFacultyOffices] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ShowSpecialisms] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CustomisedShowFacultyOffices] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CustomisedShowSpecialisms] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [ShowLeaveDetails] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CustomisedShowLeaveDetails] [bit] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ShowFundingApplications]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ShowAssociateMemberInformation]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ShowVisitorInformation]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ShowPostholdingDetails]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ShowWorkloadDetails]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CustomisedShowAssociateInfo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CustomisedShowVisitorInfo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CustomisedShowPostholdingInfo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CustomisedShowFundingInfo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CustomisedShowWorkloadInfo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ShowFacultyOffices]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ShowSpecialisms]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CustomisedShowFacultyOffices]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CustomisedShowSpecialisms]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ShowLeaveDetails]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CustomisedShowLeaveDetails]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([Location])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[Locations] ([LocationName])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[People]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PersonType])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[PersonTypes] ([PersonType])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO



CREATE TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors](
    [VisitorID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [DateOfApplication] [datetime] NULL,
    [HomeInstitution] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Position] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Address1] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Address2] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [PostCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [SponsorName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [SponsorDocumentPath] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [VisitStart] [datetime] NULL,
    [VisitEnd] [datetime] NULL,
    [AssociatedCollege] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [IntendToCollaborateOnResearchProject] [bit] NULL,
    [IntendToOrganiseAnEvent] [bit] NULL,
    [IntendToWriteArticle] [bit] NULL,
    [IntendToDevelopResearchProposal] [bit] NULL,
    [IntendToProvideSpecialSeminar] [bit] NULL,
    [PlannedActivitiesFurtherDetails] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RequireWorkstation] [bit] NULL,
    [RequireUniversityCard] [bit] NULL,
    [FundingDetails] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [VisitorsFeeAmount] [decimal](9, 2) NULL,
    [EquipmentFees] [decimal](9, 2) NULL,
    [DatePaid] [datetime] NULL,
    [PaymentReference] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [OriginatingResearchCentre] [int] NULL,
    [SignatureReceived] [bit] NULL,
    [ApplicationStatus] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [FundingDocumentPath] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ApplicationDecisionDate] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VisitorID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DateOfApplication]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IntendToCollaborateOnResearchProject]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IntendToOrganiseAnEvent]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IntendToWriteArticle]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IntendToDevelopResearchProposal]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IntendToProvideSpecialSeminar]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RequireWorkstation]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RequireUniversityCard]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SignatureReceived]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([OriginatingResearchCentre])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[VisitorsResearchCentres] ([CentreID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__AcademicV__Perso__1DB06A4F] FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
REFERENCES [People].[People] ([PersonID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__AcademicV__Perso__1DB06A4F]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fkVisitors_VisitorStatus] FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationStatus])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[VisitorApplicationStatuses] ([ApplicationStatus])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fkVisitors_VisitorStatus]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [ix_AR_PersonVisitors]    Script Date: 25/07/2023 13:01:51 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_AR_PersonVisitors] ON [Visitors].[AcademicVisitors]
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO





CREATE TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails](
    [AssociateMemberID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [HasWebProfile] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Published] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [WebCategory] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [FacultyEmployee] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OtherAffiliation] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [YearOfDoctorate] [int] NULL,
    [RefereeeName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [PathToCV] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [PathToSupportingReference] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [RationaleForFacultyAssociation] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [RenewalApplication] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ExistingUniversityCardNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [BodCardEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FacultyMembership] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Congregation] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SubCategory] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [MembershipEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [HasLeft] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [TS] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [MembershipDuration] [varchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AssociateMemberID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [HasWebProfile]
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Published]
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [FacultyEmployee]
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RenewalApplication]
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Congregation]
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [HasLeft]
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([Category])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[AssociateMemberCategories] ([Category])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__Associate__Perso__7EF6D905] FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
REFERENCES [People].[People] ([PersonID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__Associate__Perso__7EF6D905]
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([WebCategory])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[WebCategories] ([WebCategory])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_AssociateMembershipDetails_SubCategories] FOREIGN KEY([SubCategory])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[AssociateMemberSubCategories] ([SubCategory])
GO

ALTER TABLE [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_AssociateMembershipDetails_SubCategories]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [ix_AR_PersonAssociateMembers]    Script Date: 25/07/2023 13:04:55 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_AR_PersonAssociateMembers] ON [AssociateMembers].[AssociateMembershipDetails]
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO




CREATE TABLE [Workload].[PostHolderWorkload](
    [PersonWorkloadID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [TermID] [int] NULL,
    [WorkloadType] [int] NULL,
    [Quantity] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    [TotalWorkload] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    [WorkloadDetails] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [TS] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonWorkloadID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Workload].[PostHolderWorkload]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
REFERENCES [People].[People] ([PersonID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Workload].[PostHolderWorkload]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([TermID])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[Terms] ([TermID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Workload].[PostHolderWorkload]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([WorkloadType])
REFERENCES [Workload].[WorkloadTypes] ([WorkloadTypeID])
GO

/****** Object:  Index [ix_AR_PersonWorkload]    Script Date: 25/07/2023 13:05:50 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_AR_PersonWorkload] ON [Workload].[PostHolderWorkload]
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO





CREATE TABLE [Workload].[LeaveBooked](
    [LeaveBookedID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [TypeOfLeave] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [StartTerm] [int] NULL,
    [EndTerm] [int] NULL,
    [LeaveStatus] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OriginalWebID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ApplicationNotes] [varchar](3000) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LeaveBookedID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Workload].[LeaveBooked]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([EndTerm])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[Terms] ([TermID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Workload].[LeaveBooked]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([LeaveStatus])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[LeaveStatuses] ([LeaveStatus])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Workload].[LeaveBooked]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
REFERENCES [People].[People] ([PersonID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Workload].[LeaveBooked]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([StartTerm])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[Terms] ([TermID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Workload].[LeaveBooked]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([TypeOfLeave])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[LeaveTypes] ([LeaveType])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

/****** Object:  Index [ix_AR_PersonLeaveBooked]    Script Date: 25/07/2023 13:06:44 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_AR_PersonLeaveBooked] ON [Workload].[LeaveBooked]
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO





CREATE TABLE [Finance].[FundingApplications](
    [ApplicationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FacultyDeadline] [datetime] NULL,
    [RSDeadline] [datetime] NULL,
    [FunderDeadline] [datetime] NULL,
    [ApplicantPersonID] [int] NULL,
    [ProjectShortTitle] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ProjectFullTitle] [varchar](3000) NULL,
    [FunderReference] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [FundingBodyID] [int] NULL,
    [SchemeOrAwardType] [int] NULL,
    [InternalReferenceNum] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [X5Reference] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [AmountRequested] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [AmountForOverheads] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [AmountAwarded] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [LengthOfGrant] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RSInformed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ChancesOfSuccess] [decimal](4, 3) NULL,
    [ApplicationStatus] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Notes] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [OracleProjectNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DateOutcomeExpected] [datetime] NULL,
    [SchemeClosingDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CollaboratorsExist] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LeadCollaborator] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentFolder] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Withdrawn] [bit] NULL,
    [ApplicationUnsuccessful] [bit] NULL,
    [TS] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ApplicationID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Finance].[FundingApplications] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RSInformed]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Finance].[FundingApplications] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CollaboratorsExist]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Finance].[FundingApplications] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LeadCollaborator]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Finance].[FundingApplications] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Withdrawn]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Finance].[FundingApplications] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ApplicationUnsuccessful]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Finance].[FundingApplications]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ApplicantPersonID])
REFERENCES [People].[People] ([PersonID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Finance].[FundingApplications]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationStatus])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[FundingApplicationStatuses] ([ApplicationStatus])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Finance].[FundingApplications]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([FundingBodyID])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[FundingBodies] ([FundingBodyID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Finance].[FundingApplications]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([SchemeOrAwardType])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[FundingAwardTypes] ([AwardTypeID])
GO




/****** Object:  Index [ix_AR_PersonReasearchFundingApplications]    Script Date: 25/07/2023 13:07:32 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_AR_PersonReasearchFundingApplications] ON [Finance].[FundingApplications]
(
    [ApplicantPersonID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO





CREATE TABLE [HR].[PostHolders](
    [PostHolderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [AppointmentID] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [EmployeeStatus] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [EmployeeSubstatus] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [TargetEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ActualEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [WorkgroupID] [int] NULL,
    [College] [int] NULL,
    [PostTitle] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [PostText] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [PostCategory] [int] NULL,
    [HoursWorked] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [Grade] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Point] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [TS] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [ContractStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PostHolderID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [HR].[PostHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([College])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[Colleges] ([CollegeID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [HR].[PostHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeStatus])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[EmployeeStatuses] ([EmployeeStatusOption])
GO

ALTER TABLE [HR].[PostHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeSubstatus])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[EmployeeSubstatuses] ([SubstatusOption])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [HR].[PostHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
REFERENCES [People].[People] ([PersonID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [HR].[PostHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PostCategory])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[PostCategories] ([PostCategoryID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [HR].[PostHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([WorkgroupID])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[Workgroups] ([WorkgroupID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [HR].[PostHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_PostHolders_JobTitles] FOREIGN KEY([PostTitle])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[PostTitles] ([PostTitle])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [HR].[PostHolders] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_PostHolders_JobTitles]
GO






/****** Object:  Index [ix_AR_PersonReasearchFundingApplications]    Script Date: 25/07/2023 13:07:32 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_AR_PersonPostholders] ON [HR].[PostHolders]
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



CREATE TABLE [FacultyOffices].[FacultyOfficeHolders](
    [FacultyOfficeHolderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FacultyOfficeID] [int] NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [TermID] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [BuyoutTaken] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Notes] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [TS] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [GroupingID] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FacultyOfficeHolderID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [FacultyOffices].[FacultyOfficeHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([FacultyOfficeID])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[FacultyOffices] ([FacultyOfficeID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [FacultyOffices].[FacultyOfficeHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
REFERENCES [People].[People] ([PersonID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [FacultyOffices].[FacultyOfficeHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([Status])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[FacultyOfficeHolderStatuses] ([Status])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [FacultyOffices].[FacultyOfficeHolders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([TermID])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[Terms] ([TermID])
GO




/****** Object:  Index [ix_AR_PersonFacultyOffices]    Script Date: 25/07/2023 13:10:21 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_AR_PersonFacultyOffices] ON [FacultyOffices].[FacultyOfficeHolders]
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO




CREATE TABLE [People].[PersonSpecialisms](
    [PersonSpecialismID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [SpecialismID] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonSpecialismID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[PersonSpecialisms]  WITH NOCHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
REFERENCES [People].[People] ([PersonID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [People].[PersonSpecialisms]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([SpecialismID])
REFERENCES [Lookups].[Specialisms] ([SpecialismID])
GO

/****** Object:  Index [ix_AR_PersonSpecialisms]    Script Date: 25/07/2023 13:11:04 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_AR_PersonSpecialisms] ON [People].[PersonSpecialisms]
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And here's the query plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJLVRNT9n

Comment: Can you share some info on the involved tables?   Like is `PersonID` unique in the table `People` ?  For performance tips it would be usefull to know how all your involved tables are created, and an execution plan (which can be posted here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ )

Comment: Do you have indexes on personId on all those joined tables? and are all those "ApplicationID etc" part of clustered index?

Comment: it might (*might*) improve the query to convert it to bunch of correlated subqueries and remove the distinct part. Something like: select p.personid, (select top 1 1 from Visitors.AcademicVisitors av where p.PersonID = av.PersonID) as VisitorInfo...

Comment: I would immediately look at removing distinct if you can, that requires sorting the data; probably these outer joins should be *exists* instead.

Comment: We need at a bare minimum: the table definitions (including indexes), and the query plan. This question is not answerable otherwise.

Comment: I have the SQL statements to build these tables plus the indexes - it's too big for a sqlfiddle.com - am I okay to post the scripts in my question?

Comment: Comment out each of the case expressions and left joins and add back one at a time to see where performance tanks

Comment: This might allow larger queries: https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-

Comment: dbfiddle.uk gave errors so I've posted the complete SQL above - hope that's ok.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason why I didn't post the complete object definitions originally was that my intent in the question wasn't so much "Why is my query running slowly" as "If I want to achieve this objective, is there a more efficient way that this type of query, using these outer joins". So, happy to get any advice, but I was interested in the concept of the best way to find out if there are related records, rather than solving this specific performance issue.

Comment: See earlier comment about correlated subqueries (The comment with [might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762236/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-this-query#comment135329102_76762236) in it )

Comment: One thing that would massively speed things up would be, if you added an integer column to your People table and then used it as a Bit-wise Flag, where your subsidiary tables have flag values (1, 2, 4, 8 etc) .  You then set (unset) the appropriate bit, when adding (deleting) in the given table.  Once you have done this, you don't need any left joins at all, you can simply read off the values from the respective bits.

Comment: The thing is, you can't decouple the performance from the best way to do something. The query purely describes the results you want. How the engine does that is up to it i.e. how you write the query doesn't directly determine performance. The normal rule of thumb is, write the query so that it makes good logical sense and then performance tune only if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it more efficient if you remove the `DISTINCT` and write the joins as `CASE WHEN EXISTS` or `IIF(EXISTS`, because the server can transform those into semi-joins with a pass-through existence column.

Every one of these tables *must* have an index on their `PersonID` join column for this to perform well.

```sql
SELECT
  P.PersonID,
  IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM Visitors.AcademicVisitors av
      WHERE p.PersonID = av.PersonID
    ), 1, 0) AS VisitorInfo,
  IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM AssociateMembers.AssociateMembershipDetails amd
      WHERE p.PersonID = amd.PersonID
    ), 1, 0) AS AssociateMemberInfo,
  IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM Workload.PostHolderWorkload phw
      WHERE p.PersonID = phw.PersonID
    ), 1, 0) AS WorkloadInfo,
  IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM Finance.FundingApplications fa
      WHERE p.PersonID = fa.ApplicantPersonID
    ), 1, 0) AS FundingInfo,
  IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM HR.PostHolders ph
      WHERE p.PersonID = ph.PersonID
    ), 1, 0) AS PostHolderInfo,
  IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM FacultyOffices.FacultyOfficeHolders foh
      WHERE p.PersonID = foh.PersonID
    ), 1, 0) AS FacultyOfficeHolderInfo,
  IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM People.PersonSpecialisms ps
      WHERE p.PersonID = ps.PersonID
    ), 1, 0) AS PersonSpecialismInfo,
  IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM Workload.LeaveBooked lb
      WHERE p.PersonID = lb.PersonID
    ), 1, 0) AS PersonLeaveInfo
FROM People.People p;
```

Comment: Perfect - that reduced the query time significantly. Thanks for your help. I've not heard of semi-joins... must go read up now!